# Working with SSH connection and Github workflow

Tags: github, ssh, workflow, headless

in working on an experiment on a ML technique that required me to use a better machine for computational purposes, so they gave me an SSH connection to the machine. Also the data were stored in that server.

My workflow was this:

(I'm working on a headless server)

1. Connect my local machine via ssh and run the script for the experiments...

On that machine I could only use vim without all my setup

2. If I want to change something I have to change it in my local then push the changes
3. I pull the changes on the remote server and then I try a new experiment.
4. Occasionally I had to push from the remote server the results (plots and more) and then pull them from local to work on that and push again eventually.

I think there is a flaw in this, and there's a better way to manage all of these things.

Do you have some ideas?

What i need is just a clever way to do not push every change i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is to use an IDE like VSCode with the [Remote - SSH extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh), following [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial).

That way, your local VSCode, on your local machine, displays and edits directly files on the remote machine, without you having to pull/push them.

Depending on that extension, you might still need a separate SSH session in order to git add/commit those modified files.

Comment: Oh this was just the right tool I needed, I just wanted to knew it before all my shenanigans with git. Thank you!